# WxWidgets Hello World fails to compile: "wchar_t must be available"

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

When I try to compile the hello world application from wxWidgets in MS Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, I get a large number of errors. I believe the key error is `#error: "wchar_t must be available"`. As far as I have looked there is only one other person I have found with this error, and when they asked, they didn't get any useful answers. [http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/197245/]

What can I do to make this program compile successfully, and how can I ensure that I don't get the same error on future (real) projects?

I just started learning wxWidgets and I installed version 3.0.4 on my laptop. I downloaded the installer then used Visual Studio to compile the libraries as instructed. I believe the installation completed successfully as all the sample projects compiled and ran successfully. however when I tried to compile the provided hello world application in its own project, I got the aforementioned errors. I have ensured that the wxWidgets headers are being linked, although since I am new to using non-built-in libraries, I may have made a mistake. I am unsure why the sample projects would work when hello world doesn't.

```
// wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();
private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
};
enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Hello World")
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
        "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
}
void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
        "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

This is an exact replica of the code available at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html
I have included the code here in case the code on the website is updated.

As you can imagine I would expect the program to compile and run normally, but instead, I have gotten a large number of errors, all of which are listed in this image:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/452995181667418119/527236184326275113/unknown.png

Here are some interesting observations I made:

- The majority of the errors stem from the compiler not being able to find the definition of class wxFrame
- The class wxApp is still defined and I can inherit the class myApp from it.
- `chartype.h` gives an error that wchar_t must be available, even though according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/ it is built-in to c++ and I don't need to include any other headers.
- The error in `chartype.h` is found in this code snippet:

```
/* Unicode support requires wchar_t */
#if !wxUSE_WCHAR_T
    #error "wchar_t must be available"
#endif /* Unicode */
```

- As far as I can tell, the #define is never actually set in any source files I can find, but it represents whether the wchar_t type exists. I added a small variable into my code of this type and it was created fine

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That error ([C1189](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1189?view=vs-2017)) is caused by a preprocessor definition. Can you take a look at the offending file "chartype.h" to see why it is caused (the IDE should help color the correct preprocessor definitions)

Comment: @UnholySheep the error is in a #if which references a #define. As far as I can tell this constant represents whether wchar_t can be found. None of the definitions of it in the wxWidgets library are actually used as they are all found in #ifndef blocks and it seems to be already defined, maybe it is built into c++?

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/chartype.h) this is using a custom define `wxUSE_WCHAR_T` which is definitely not built into C++. *Something*  must be setting it to `0`, either through a `#define` or possibly a definition in your project settings

Comment: I changed the target to x64 and I got the same errors, except now the compiler 'can't open wxprec.h' even though the file exists

Comment: @HDSQ.mid, you said that all samples are compiled and run fine. Can you open the minimal workspace and see what it defines and what are its project properties it defines. Then look at the properties of your own project. Fix any inconsistencies. Build and run. Enjoy. BTW, it is recommended to copy the project files to the new place in order to start your own. Starting with the 3.1.1 there is a template to start a new project.

Comment: @Igor I just copied the project files to my source directory and they stopped working. I got the same errors as in hello world

Comment: Have you tried usnig the wxUSE_WCHAR_T definition right after the inclusion of your wx headers? I'm skeptical, because the wx headers are supposed to define it regardless of your configuration in the setup header.
I know it won't compile, but I hope IntelliSense will help us with that.

Comment: @TudorVersoiu makes no difference.

Comment: Tried rebuilding the library and I got the same error while building it :/

Comment: @HDSQ.mid I asked that because I wanted to know whether the macro definition was undefined, defined to zero, or just defined before the code that raises the error. Thanks.

Comment: @HDSQ.mid, you said that you copied the project files over. Did you change the properties of the project, such as "Include directories" and "Library directories"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you compiling the hello world example? Your image shows errors like `E0020` and `E0070` which are not standard MSVC compiler errors *at* *all* (those would be of `Cnnnn` form). You need to create a new "Win32 application" project and change the settings as explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.0.4/docs/msw/install.txt#L458) (as you're using MSVC, last paragraph applies to your case).

Alternatively, download the more recent v3.1.2 and just reference the new `wxwidgets.props` file from your project as [explained here](http://wxwidgets.org/blog/2018/11/using-wxwidgets-with-msvs/).

Comment: I installed v3.1.2 and used the .props file and then it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found out that wxWidgets doesn't define wxUSE_WCHAR_T, but it does define SIZEOF_WCHAR_T. It seems odd to me.
However, after some more searching I found this page:
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide

What seems important from here is:
Preprocessor definitions:

- _UNICODE - Add this if you are using Unicode (note that this definition may be inherited from a project default - see note below)

This also reminded me how stupid I am because at some point in time I read an introductory tutorial on Windows Api and it said clearly do define UNICODE if you plan on using it.

```
#define UNICODE // Controls the windows library definitions
#define _UNICODE // Controls the C library definitions
```

I am not 100% sure, but I suspect that this would be the problem.

Comment: When I define _UNICODE, I get a warning about redefining a declaration, so it must already be defined. same with UNICODE